# FB Feedshare not working with Unity 2018.4 when .net 4 selected

Tags: .net, unity-game-engine, facebook-graph-api

I have a Unity app which I migrated from 2017.4.32 to 2018.4.9.
My app has two sharing functions, one uses FB.ShareLink() and the other FB.FeedShare()

After converting from 2017 to 2018 both share functions worked.
I updating the "Scripting Runtime Version" from .Net 3.5 (deprecated) to .Net 4.x.

FB.ShareLink() works like before, but FB.FeedShare shows a Facebook error UI with the message "Invalid access_token".

The FB SDK is installed with Gradle:

```
implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-core:[5,6)' 
implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-login:[5,6)' 
implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-share:[5,6)'
```

I can switch back to .Net 3.5 and everything works again, but trying to migrate to .Net 4 to fix other issues

I tried:
 - reinstalling the FB Unity SDK (facebook-unity-sdk-7.17.2)
 - updating Unity from 2018.4.9 to 2018.4.10
 - logging in and out of FB

The only related message in the logs i see is:

```
10-01 21:58:10.992  7453  7521 V com.facebook.unity.FB: FeedShare({"link":"http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.myapp","linkName":"New High Score","linkCaption":"My Game","linkDescription":"Can you beat my score...","picture":"http://img.asdfasdf.com/asdfasdf.png","callback_id":"3"})
```

[image: FB invalid access_token]

Answer (score 0):

ok here is a fix that worked for my account.  I had to go into Facebook, click settings, then "Apps and Websites".  Select my app with the issue and click "Remove".  Once I start the app again, it forces me to login, but then the problem is gone and FeedShare() once again works as expected.

Unfortunately there is no way in code to fix it on other people's devices.  Or perhaps it only happened on my device?